# How to display numeric keyboard for Telerik RadMaskedInput control in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, telerik

In my Xamarin.Forms project, I am using the Telerik UI for Xamarin.  For the `RadMaskedInput` control, **I'd like to know the easiest way to display the numeric on-screen keyboard** (as opposed to the full alphanumeric keyboard).

I am initializing the component from XAML as follows:

```
<telerikInput:RadMaskedInput 
    x:Name="heightEntry" 
    Mask="0'00&quot;" 
    Placeholder="#" 
    WatermarkText="Height"/>
```

The above displays a "masked" text box that allows the user to enter their height in feet and inches (*e.g.*, 5'11").  Text entry on Android is especially cumbersome as the user must manually change the keyboard to numeric for *each* character typed.

Using the native Xamarin.Forms `Entry` control, which is not "masked", this would be easily accomplished by setting the `Keyboard` property to `"Numeric"` as follows:

```
<Entry 
    x:Name="heightEntry"
    Keyboard="Numeric" 
    Placeholder="Height"/>
```

However, the `RadMaskedInput` component lacks a `Keyboard` property.  A description of the easiest way to display the numeric on-screen keyboard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't use Telerik, but i'm sure by the documentation that you can use `RadMaskedNumericInput` [Telerik RadMaskedInput](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radmaskedinput/overview)

Comment: Thank you @FabriBertani, but that appears to be following the documentation for their UI controls for WPF.  The Xamarin Forms UI documentation [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/maskedinput/getting-started) for `RadMaskedInput` unfortunately has no numeric counterpart.

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/forums/keyboard-type-with-masked-input

Comment: @Jason, that looks promising, however it is not completely clear to me how that is referenced from within the project.  Perhaps you could post an answer detailing that?  :)

Comment: custom renderers are extensively documented on the Xamarin site

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the Keyboard property of the RadMaskedInput control. The property is available in Telerik UI for Xamarin version 2021.1.224.1 https://feedback.telerik.com/xamarin/1366238-maskedinput-add-option-for-setting-the-virtual-keyboard

Example with RadMaskedInput control and Numeric Keyboard type:

```
<telerikInput:RadMaskedInput Keyboard="Numeric"/>
```